# Adding user to servers' administrator group, encountering error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a script that will let me add a user to a group of servers, and then remove said user from the group at a later date. Right now I can make the script work when I only have one server but when I use a comma-separated list I get the following error: `Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown error (0x80005000)"`

I'm running the script as an admin on the machines necessary, and my execution policy is set to allow the script to run on any of the servers I'm targeting. Additionally, the domain situation is:

Target servers:

```
DomainA/ServerA
DomainA/ServerB
```

Users:

```
DomainB/UserA
```

I can add the user fine from being logged in to the server. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
param($serverName, $group, $user, $action)

if (! $serverName) {
  $serverlist = read-host "Enter server(comma separated list): ".split(",")
}

if (! $group) {
  $group = read-host "Enter group: "
}

if (! $action) {
  $action = read-host "Add, Remove or List: "
}

$objGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$serverName/$group")

if ($action.ToLower() -eq "list") {
  $members = @($objGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
  $members | foreach {
    $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
  }
} else {
  if (! $user) {
    $user = read-host "Enter domain user id: "
  }

  foreach ($serverName in $serverList) {
    $serverName = $serverName.Trim().ToUpper()
    $objADUser = [ADSI]("WinNT://$serverName/$user")
  }

  $objGroup.PSBase.Invoke($action,$objADUser.PSBase.Path)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `read-host "Enter server(comma separated list): ".split(",")` to `(read-host "Enter server(comma separated list)").split(",")`  (parenthesis are added)

Comment: That sort of works, in that it no longer displays an error. Instead, it works but only on the last entry in the comma delimited list. I tried putting a foreach statement at the end (in that last if statement) but it only seems to pick up the last entered server name.

Comment: You do need to add the final Invoke method call to the existing For loop. I think you are dealing with two issues: getting the input from read-host correctly and getting the ADSI add/remove to work. So for debugging I suggest adding something like `write-host $action user $($objADUser.path)` in the for loop before Invoke() call. That'll tell you if input is correct. As far as getting the ADSI method to work will need you to provide more details on your config